# Posicionar elementos na horizontal

Tags: html, css

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código, mas todos os elementos vem um em baixo do outro, gostaria que eles viesse um ao lado do outro, é possível sem ter que mexe na posição de cada elemento separadamente?

```html
 <div class="back">
                    <p class="p3">10</p>
                    <p class="p3">20</p>
                    <p class="p3">30</p>
                    <p class="p3">40</p>
                    <p class="p3">50</p>
                    <p class="p3">60</p>
                    <p class="p3">70</p>
                    <p class="p3">80</p>
                    <p class="p3">90</p>
                    <p class="p3">100</p>
                    <p class="p3">110</p>
                    <p class="p3">120</p>
                    <p class="p3">130</p>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elementos `<p>` são por padrão em bloco (estilo do user agent usa `display: block;`), então basta trocar por ou outro elemento que seja `inline`, como `<span>`, algo como:

```html
 <div class="back">
    <span class="p3">10</span>
    <span class="p3">20</span>
    <span class="p3">30</span>
    <span class="p3">40</span>
    <span class="p3">50</span>
    <span class="p3">60</span>
    <span class="p3">70</span>
    <span class="p3">80</span>
    <span class="p3">90</span>
    <span class="p3">100</span>
    <span class="p3">110</span>
    <span class="p3">120</span>
    <span class="p3">130</span>
 </div>
```

Note que se os elementos atingirem a largura limite do elemento pai ou do view-port (ou do body, depende de como configurou) você poderia usar `white-space: nowrap;`, exemplo:

```css
.back {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="back">
    <span class="p3">10</span>
    <span class="p3">20</span>
    <span class="p3">30</span>
    <span class="p3">40</span>
    <span class="p3">50</span>
    <span class="p3">60</span>
    <span class="p3">70</span>
    <span class="p3">80</span>
    <span class="p3">90</span>
    <span class="p3">100</span>
    <span class="p3">110</span>
    <span class="p3">120</span>
    <span class="p3">130</span>
    <span class="p3">10</span>
    <span class="p3">20</span>
    <span class="p3">30</span>
    <span class="p3">40</span>
    <span class="p3">50</span>
    <span class="p3">60</span>
    <span class="p3">70</span>
    <span class="p3">80</span>
    <span class="p3">90</span>
    <span class="p3">100</span>
    <span class="p3">110</span>
    <span class="p3">120</span>
    <span class="p3">130</span>
    <span class="p3">10</span>
    <span class="p3">20</span>
    <span class="p3">30</span>
    <span class="p3">40</span>
    <span class="p3">50</span>
    <span class="p3">60</span>
    <span class="p3">70</span>
    <span class="p3">80</span>
    <span class="p3">90</span>
    <span class="p3">100</span>
    <span class="p3">110</span>
    <span class="p3">120</span>
    <span class="p3">130</span>
 </div>
```

Comment: Legal, não sabia disso, obrigado

Comment: Ainda não posso aceitar a resposta, mas quando liberarem eu aceito

Comment: @JeffHenrique teste antes com calma, não tem prazo para aceitar a resposta, pode aceitar ela quando estiver confiante que resolveu o  seu problema, se não tiver resolvido basta comentar aqui.

Comment: Ok, mas eu testei e funcionou como queria, obrigado